# Term to a describe group of words which define a range of intensity for a target word

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Suppose the target word is "calm".
What might be the term for a group of words that mean or describe the range of "calm"-ness:?. (i.e. "least calm", "less calm", "calm", "very calm", "extremely calm")

Also, in this example, I don't expect the word replacing "least calm" to be an antonym of "calm". It should be a synonym.

Comment: degree of calmness? adverbs?

Comment: Would "a scale of calmness" work?

Comment: **gradation(s)**, n. *A scale or series of degrees in rank, merit, intensity, or difference from some particular type; the fact or condition of including or being arranged*

Comment: *Intensity, magnitude, spectrum*...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think gradation comes close to what I was looking for.
I was hoping for something technical that would at least lead to previous literature / research on the subject.

Comment: If you want "something technical", look up ***cline***. Sorely-missed linguistics professor John Lawler was fond of that term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An antonym for "continuum" to describe a limited set of possible options](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29236/an-antonym-for-continuum-to-describe-a-limited-set-of-possible-options) (eg _range_ [of values]) Or [Is there a linguistic term that denotes 'levels of comparison' of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230727/is-there-a-linguistic-term-that-denotes-the-class-of-properties-that-words-of-co/230738#230738) (gradation)?  I don't think there are any word-specific hyponyms.

Comment: I think you’re referring to [*grading adverbs*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbs-of-Degree.htm).